# How to correctly write inline django-tag in HamlPy

Tags: python, django, django-templates, haml, hamlpy

How can I write an inline tag in [HamlPy](https://github.com/nyaruka/django-hamlpy)? For example, in this case:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'profile_list_2.css' %}">
```

I know I can write it in Django style, and it will work:

```
%link(src="{% static 'ajax.js %}'")
```

But it seems to me it's not the HamlPy-style. I suppose there is way to make it more like Haml-style code.

I tried:

```
%link(src="-static 'ajax.js'")

%link(src="|% static 'ajax.js'")
```

but it's not working. How can I do it more succinctly?

Comment: Please create a little Haml snippet, let Haml generate the HTML, and include that into the question to show us what it's doing, and then modify it to show us what you want. This is all in addition to your Haml already in the question. Don't add "edited" or "updated" tags to mark the changes, instead incorporate that into the question as if it'd been there initially. "[Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648)"
helps explain it.

Comment: Haml is a Ruby-based app, so the [tag:haml] tag really only applies to Ruby. I added the [tag:python] tag to see if that'll pull in people with HamlPy knowledge.